# Problems with forward selection with stepAIC R

Tags: r, feature-detection, logistic-regression

I have a quick question about R forward selection. So I have a list of 30 variables that I've trained with glm.

```
  model1 = glm(eggs ~ ., data = traindata1, family = binomial())
```

The . stands for 31 variables that are in the trainingdata. So then I've loaded MASS and am trying to run stepAIC with forward selection. 
I run:

```
  step1 = stepAIC(model1, selection = "forward")
```

However, it just gives me the same final model as initial model. And it ran once. When I do:

```
  step1 = stepAIC(model1, selection = "backward")
```

It works, and gives me a bunch of models. How do I exactly get the "forward" one to work? I'm trying to include like one variable in the mode1, and then name scope as something different but it's not working. I don't want to have to add every variable individually.

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: Forward selection adds variables - how can it do so if you start from the full model? Start from the intercept and specify the scope (as far as i can remember the args)

Comment: quick ex. `m <- lm(mpg ~ 1, mtcars); stepAIC(m, direction="forward", scope=list(lower=m, upper=~wt+disp+cyl+gear))`

Comment: @user20650 post this as an answer

Comment: @TMS; okay ... done

Answer (score 6):

Forward selection adds variables. It cannot do this if you start from the full model. You can start from the intercept, for example, and specify the scope.

Quick example

```
m <- lm(mpg ~ 1, mtcars)
stepAIC(m, direction="forward", scope=list(lower=m, upper=~wt+disp+cyl+gear))
```